# Potential hazards of adding lots of Disposables to a CompositeDisposable

Tags: android, mvvm, rx-java, rx-java2

When going through a lot of articles that talk about Android MVVM architectures with RxJava 2 (such as [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/mvvm-architecture-using-livedata-rxjava-and-new-dagger-android-injection-639837b1eb6c)), you often see something that looks like the following:

```
class LobbyViewModel extends ViewModel {

... 

void loadCommonGreeting() {
    loadGreeting(loadCommonGreetingUseCase.execute());
}

void loadLobbyGreeting() {
    loadGreeting(loadLobbyGreetingUseCase.execute());
}

MutableLiveData<Response<String>> getResponse() {
    return response;
}

MutableLiveData<Boolean> getLoadingStatus() {
    return loadingStatus;
}

private void loadGreeting(Single<String> single) {
    disposables.add(single
            .subscribeOn(schedulersFacade.io())
            .observeOn(schedulersFacade.ui())
            .doOnSubscribe(s -> loadingStatus.setValue(true))
            .doAfterTerminate(() -> loadingStatus.setValue(false))
            .subscribe(
                    greeting -> response.setValue(Response.success(greeting)),
                    throwable -> response.setValue(Response.error(throwable))
            )
    );
}
```

When you look at the logic of the above, you see that every time the user triggers an action, (`loadCommonGreeting()`/`loadLobbyGreeting()`) a new disposable will be added to the `CompositeDisposable` variable `disposables`.

In this case it probably won't be a huge deal, but I can imagine that maybe in some other scenarios the number of `Disposables` linked to the `CompositeDisposables` could run up to the thousands or more.

Is this considered a good or safe practice?

Comment: The [RxJava 2 Extensions](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#subscribeautorelease) project recently added tools to automatically remove completed consumers from `CompositeDisposable`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each subscription in the `CompositeDisposable` completes, there will be only a small amount of memory leakage over time.

If you are concerned about it, you should be able to create the disposable ahead of time in `loadGreeting()`. Add a `doOnUnsubscribe()` operation that will remove the disposable from the `CompositeDisposable()`.